# I expected a different output from this on Python. What is the logic behind this?

Tags: python

```
first = [2, 4, 6]
second = [2, 4, 6]
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            continue
        print(i, '*', j, '= ', i * j)
```

Here is the output:

```
2 * 4 =  8
2 * 6 =  12
4 * 2 =  8
4 * 6 =  24
6 * 2 =  12
6 * 4 =  24
```

I would expect something like this, `2*2=4`, `4*4=16`, `6*6=36`. Because we check if two variables are equal and then continue.

Comment: [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) means to restart the loop and not execute any more of the code in the loop after that statement. You should be using `if i != j` instead

Comment: You put in `if i == j: continue`, making it skip the `print` if they're both the same.

Comment: `continue` means you continue the loop to the next iteration, so you skip the end of the loop and start again to the next iteration.

Comment: Follow it step by step at http://pythontutor.com…

Comment: `continue` means to continue to the next iteration, not continue with the rest of the body.

Comment: `for i, j in zip(first, second): print(i, '*', j, '= ' i * j)`

Answer (score 1):

"continue" means "immediately start the next iteration of the loop without executing the rest of the loop", so it skips this iteration.

I imagine you though it just mean to continue the iteration, but that wouldn't make much sense as this happens without any keyword

Generally it's a good idea to avoid using the keywords "continue" and "break" too much. In your case, you could just do:

```
first = [2, 4, 6]
second = [2, 4, 6]
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            print(i, '*', j, '= ', i * j)
```

This would have the result you expect

Alternatively you could use continue to do what you wanted, by inverting the condition:

```
first = [2, 4, 6]
second = [2, 4, 6]
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i =! j:
            continue
        print(i, '*', j, '= ', i * j)
```

But if you compare both code I propose here, the first one is much clearer, shorter and there isn't some block of code magically skipped, so it's very advisable to avoid the keyword continue unless it's absolutely necessary, which really doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword continue in python loops means you are gonna stop current iteration and go straight into next one, meaning none of the following lines is gonna get executed.

Concluding equal numbers will not have the expression printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your print is outside the if condition and there is no need of 'continue'.

Try:

```
first = [2, 4, 6]
second = [2, 4, 6]
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            print(i, '*', j, '= ', i * j)
```